# LibGDX image touchDown slow

Tags: java, android, ios, android-studio, libgdx

Currently I am working on a LibGdx project using Android Studio in Java.

I have images as buttons that the app user can click. (Ex: Play Button)

But i feel i am doing something wrong since after i click the image, it takes about 2 seconds to actually go to the Play Screen.

My Play Button's listener is pretty basic

**Play Button Listener:**

```
 playButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            state.set(new SelectionState(state, prefs, getImageManager()));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I do not know what other information to include, sorry! But my main question is why does it take about 2 seconds to update.

I would understand if it would load all black then show the play screen if it took a second to draw it, but here it's just saying on the main screen for 2 seconds which seems like a long time when you push it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since your assets are typically loaded on the GL thread, nothing will change while the next screen is loading. If you want a black screen to appear while it's loading, you would need to actually draw a black screen before you begin loading.

Comment: @Tenfour04 shouldnt it load instantly though? And i spammed a one of my buttons and it crashed with this "
I/dalvikvm-heap: Clamp target GC heap from 71.501MB to 64.000MB
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 64412K/65543K, paused 1ms+4ms, total 61ms
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30902 SIG: 9
Application terminated."

Comment: I don't know how fast it should load because I don't know what your object loads. Textures and sounds can be time consuming. The crash is very weird but hard to debug with so little code to see. I suspect you are loading multiple copies of something once the first object finishes loading. You should use a ChangeListener instead of an InputListener on your button, and react to the `changed` method instead of touchDown. That way it won't allow multiple presses of the button to register.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks I'll try adding that tomorrow! And [This](http://pastebin.com/kC365unP) is what it basically is, multiple versions of this class for example thats the stats screen there are play screen, menu screen and those but that one is the most basic and still takes a while to load.

Comment: If your superclass constructor is creating a new Stage, that is probably what's taking so long. A Stage creates its own SpriteBatch if you don't pass an existing SpriteBatch into its constructor. A SpriteBatch is a heavy object, and it also compiles a shader when it's first loaded. You are leaking your textures by the way. And everything else if whatever your `state` object is doesn't know to dispose the current state before switching.

Comment: So first pass a SpriteBatch to the stage, how am I leaking textures? and it does dispose because whenever it changes states (state.set()) it disposes the current and creates the next state

Comment: You created new textures but never dispose them. You should have a single SpriteBatch instance that you pass from screen to screen so you never have to dispose and reload it. And yes, you pass it into the stage constructor.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Would creating one stage at start and passing it through from screen to screen be better. I could clear or dispose i don't know what methods would be best to reset the stage then the next screen could add all its Actors to the empty stage. Or is that not the best?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Also noticed the more i press play then it loads the play screen, then press press back to menu screen and repeat, it gets slower and slower if i keep going back and forth.

Comment: You could pass the Stage around instead of the SpriteBatch if you want, but minus the SpriteBatch it's not really a heavy object, so doesn't really matter. Sounds like there must be some bug if switching back and forth makes it slow down. I don't have any guesses without seeing all the code.

Comment: @Tenfour04 [This](http://pastebin.com/165Jkc9Q) is what is called when you press the play button, if i spam back and forth from example the settings to main menu it doesn't do anything but this one gets slower each time